# Why is navbar-brand hidden on chrome for mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just finished with creating my [site](http://www.emdashr.com) and have been tweaking the mobile views. Now for the life of me I cant figure out why the navbar-brand is disappearing when the site is viewed on mobile chrome or Desktop chrome with a small view port. It does appear in safari on my iPhone, so I'm sure its there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have defined your `.navbar-brand img` to have a `width: auto;` in your `@media (max-width: 767px)` declaration try to **remove** the `width: auto;`.

**E.g.**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
     .navbar-brand img {
       max-height: 40px;
       /* width: auto; */ /** comment out or remove this line **/
       margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.